# How to populate a textarea with string values derived from various checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I'm a newcomer to javascripting, but I've learned a lot by reading through the Q&As on this forum. Like they say, the best way to learn coding is to see how other people code!

I'm trying to use a javascript/html based form to manage my workflow. A little background, I'm a pathologist who generates text based reports for various patient samples. Much of the output is very amenable to the use of prewritten 'canned comments'. I would like to have such comments linked to various checkbox values, so that I can simply check the appropriate boxes, and have my report built within a textarea.

For example, if I have 4 different tissue sites:

> [] site1 [] site 2  [] site 3 [] site 4

and can choose one of 4 different diagnoses for each

> [] diagnosis1 [] diagnosis2  [] diagnosis3  [] diagnosis4

I would like to be able to choose a site and a diagnosis and have the associated values in a textarea with the output in the following format:

> SITE1, BIOPSY:
>   - DIAGNOSIS 1
>
> SITE2, BIOPSY:
>   - DIAGNOSIS 1
>
> SITE3, BIOPSY:
>   - DIAGNOSIS 3
>
> SITE4, BIOPSY:
>   - DIAGNOSIS 2

I've got some of the beginnings of a form here:

```
<body>
Duodenum sites <br/>
<form name=duodenum>
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDx1" id="duoDx1" /> DUO, NSA <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDx2" id="duoDx2" /> DUO, _ PART <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDx3" id="duoDx3" /> DUO, BULB <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDx4" id="duoDx4" /> DUO, ULCER <br />
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
Duodenum diagnoses <br/>    
<form name=duodiags>
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDiag1" id="duoDiag1" /> NSA <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDiag2" id="duoDiag2" /> FOCAL ACTIVE <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDiag3" id="duoDiag3" /> C A  <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="duoDiag4" id="duoDiag4" /> CELIAC <br />
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<textarea id="outPut" placeholder="Diagnoses" cols=80 rows=20></textarea>

</body>
```

My javascript:

```
var duoDxs = {
duoDx1: 'DUODENUM, BIOPSY: \n \n',
duoDx2: 'DUODENUM, ___ PART, BIOPSY: \n \n',
duoDx3: 'DUODENUM, BULB, BIOPSY: \n \n',
duoDx4: 'DUODENUM, "ULCER", BIOPSY: \n \n'
}

var duoDiags = {
duoDiag1: '     - NO SIGNIFICANT ABNORMALITIES \n',
duoDiag2: '     - FOCAL ACUTE INFLAMMATION\n',
duoDiag3: '     - CHRONIC AND ACTIVE DUODENITIS\n',
duoDiag4: '     - VILLOUS BLUNTING AND INCREASED INTRAEPITHELIAL LYMPHOCYTES (SEE 
COMMENT)\n'
}

var mytextbox = document.getElementById('outPut');


var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].name.indexOf('duoDx') > -1) {
inputs[i].onchange = function() {
if (this.checked) {
mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + duoDxs[this.name] + duoDiags[this.name];
} else {
mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(duoDxs[this.name], "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cXdL/1/)

But, I can't seem to get the two parts of the checkbox values to populate the textarea in the right way. I can't seem to figure out how to have the function that populates my textarea to loop through both the sites and diagnoses? Any help / education would be very much appreciated!

Thanks.
CK

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: Hi, I have tried a similar approach by "borrowing" jQuery snippets in my code, but they didn't work and I had a hard time understanding what was done, since I'm still not familiar with jQuery explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question you would like to pair a site and a diagnosis, and the diagnosis can be used several times:

```
SITE1, BIOPSY:
- DIAGNOSIS 1

SITE2, BIOPSY:
- DIAGNOSIS 1    << second usage of DIAGNOSIS 1

SITE3, BIOPSY:
- DIAGNOSIS 3

SITE4, BIOPSY:
- DIAGNOSIS 2
```

In this case a checkbox isn't the way to go. First of all, since there seems to be only *one* site for *one* diagnosis, a `<input type="radio">` would be much more appropriate. Second, the values need to be reseted after you actually provided input.

Think of your site more of a coffee vending machine: first you choose the amount of cream (the site), then the amount of sugar (the diagnosis) and either the machine automatically brews your coffee and resets the values of both to undetermined or you have to push a button to get your coffee (or whatever beverage with individual flavor the machine will give to you).

So instead of using only one mechanism for your checkboxes use two: one for the site, and one for the diagnosis. Check in bother whether the partner has already been assigned. If there is a partner, add both value to the textarea and remove the selection:

```
var choosenDiagnosis = null;
var choosenSite = null;

function testAndFill(){
    if(choosenDiagnosis !== null && choosenSite !== null){
        mytextbox.value += duoDxs[choosenSite.id]+ duoDiags[choosenDiagnosis.id] + "\n";
        choosenDiagnosis.checked = choosenSite.checked = false;
        choosenDiagnosis = choosenSite = null;
    }
}

var diagInputs = document.getElementsByName("duoDiag");
for (var i = 0; i < diagInputs.length; i++) {
    diagInputs[i].onchange = function() {
        choosenDiagnosis = this;
        testAndFill();       
    };
}
var diaxInputs = document.getElementsByName("duoDx");
for (i = 0; i < diaxInputs.length; i++) {
    diaxInputs[i].onchange = function() {
        choosenSite = this;
        testAndFill();       
    };
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8cXdL/3/)

Comment: Hi, thanks! That is a different approach to how I was thinking of doing this project, but I can see your logic. I'll need to spend time with your js to help me learn what is being done and then I can try to apply it to another draft of my template.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to share the form I made with your script suggestion as a backbone. [link](http://www.hematogones.com/pbsmears.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this

```
var duoDiags = {
             duoDiag1: '     - NO SIGNIFICANT ABNORMALITIES \n',
             duoDiag2: '     - FOCAL ACUTE INFLAMMATION\n',
             duoDiag3: '     - CHRONIC AND ACTIVE DUODENITIS\n',
             duoDiag4: '     - VILLOUS BLUNTING AND INCREASED 
                       INTRAEPITHELIAL LYMPHOCYTES  (SEE COMMENT)\n'
}
```

with

```
var duoDiags = {
    duoDx1: '     - NO SIGNIFICANT ABNORMALITIES \n \n',
    duoDx2: '     - FOCAL ACUTE INFLAMMATION\n\n',
    duoDx3: '     - CHRONIC AND ACTIVE DUODENITIS\n\n',
    duoDx4: '     - VILLOUS BLUNTING AND INCREASED INTRAEPITHELIAL LYMPHOCYTES
                     (SEE COMMENT)\n\n'
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8cXdL/2/)**